# resulf of Search on Bloomberg in Python

Tags: python, search, spyder, bloomberg

I need to pull out results of a bloomberg search (srch function) in dataframe format in Spyder (python 2.7, Spyder 2.3). 
I am using the recommended tia toolkit for historical data, but I don't know if/how to modify the inputs to get the search result?

Comment: did you figure this out? @afsi